# "One type argument expected for class BaseActivity<T : BasePresenter<*>" this Error, what should i do.?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

This is my BaseActivity,
When I take instance of this activity in another class, it  gives me below error.

> One type argument expected for class BaseActivity

Do any one know or Can any one please help to fix this?

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : BasePresenter<*>>: AppCompatActivity(){


      var presenter: T? = null
          protected set

       var view: View? = null
          protected set


      var button_backhome: ImageButton? = null

      public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          presenter = addPresenter()
          view = addView()
          onPresenterCreated(presenter!!)
      }

      override fun onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy()
          if (presenter != null) {
              presenter!!.detachView()
          }
      }


      abstract fun addPresenter(): T

      abstract fun addView(): View?

      abstract fun onPresenterCreated(presenter: T)

     companion object {
          protected var back_pressed: Long = 0
      } }
```

Comment: Incorrect code. Please post again. `abstract class BaseActivity>: AppCompatActivity(){`

Comment: @Rohit5k2  not working those solutions'